# Joomla mod_rewrite with sub-directories

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I have problem with joomla mod_rewrite.

My hosting info:
Hosting - Shared - Deluxe - Linux
Joomla:
2.5

```
root directories:
domain1com   (www.domain1.com) 
domain2com   (www.domain2.com)
domain3com   (www.domain3.com)
```

For example let's take domain1com.

```
/domain1com/configuration.php

public $live_site = 'http://www.domain1.com';
public $sef = '1'; //Search Engine Friendly URLs ON
public $sef_rewrite = '1'; //Use URL rewriting ON

**/domain1com/.htaccess**

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /domain1com/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I'm having error when I try to load:

```
www.domain1.com/example
```

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

www.domain1.com/index.php/example 
Works fine...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, as the message says: `More information about this error may be available in the server error log`, so what does the log say? Where did you get this rule-set from? Why this `RewriteBase /domain1com/`? Hard to understand, try with `RewriteBase /`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite base is relative to the domain name not the file structure. Even though there are multiple folders in the system, from the domains perspective, it is the root. You should have `RewriteBase /`.

If you were accessing the site at `www.domain1.com/domain1com/example` then you would use `RewriteBase /domain1com/`.